# I'm trying to append an image from a javascript object Array onto my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, image

So I was able to create a movie class array with 4 constructors, and a for loop with 3 iterations that represent three different movies. On the html page this allows the user to open a dropdown selection and pick one of the three movies. After hitting the submit button I want to display all the info for all the movie they selected including its image which is the difficult part. Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form > 
<select> 
</select>
<button onclick="showDetail()">Submit</button>
</form>
<p></p>
</body>

 </html>


 class movie {
name;
price;
image;
genre;
constructor(x,y,z,a){
this.name = x;
this.price = y;
this.image = z;
this.genre = a;
   }
  }


 let movies =[];
movies[0]=  new movie("Deadpool", "$6.95","Image/Deadpool.jpg", "Superhero, Action");
movies[1]=  new movie("Titanic", "$4.95", "" , "Romance, Drama");
movies[2]=  new movie("Spiderman 3", "$6.95","", "Superhero, Action");



$(document).ready(function() { console.log( "ready!");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
movies[0].image= "Image/Deadpool.jpg";
movies[1].image= "Image/Titanic.jpg"; 
movies[2].image= "Image/Spiderman.jpg";
$("select").append(`<option>${movies[i].name}</option>`); console.log(i) }});

 function showDetail(){
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    $("p").append(`${movies[i].price},${movies[i].genre}, ${movies[i].image}`);

   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append HTML using .append() but I would not recommend appending it to a paragraph tag, and using the paragraph selector, try doing this:

```
<div id="details"> </div>
```

Add the above instead of the paragraph tag and then in jquery you could so something like:

```
$('#details').append(`<h1> ${movies[i].price} </h1> <p> ${movies[i].genre} </p> <img src="${movies[i].image}" alt="movie" />
```